# how to fix lldb error of nuclide on ubuntu14.04?

Tags: lldb, hhvm, nuclide-editor

When i try to attach hhvm process to nuclide debug interface, nothing happened. In the dev console.

Please find the below screenshot for more information.

[image]

lldb is already installed. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the nuclide package's "find_lldb()" function does, so I can't tell why it is failing. If you have the source to that package you might take a look at what it is looking for.

You could try adding the directory that holds the lldb Python module to your PYTHONPATH directly.  Then lldb should just load normally without more intervention from nuclide.

The lldb driver when invoked with the -P argument will print out the directory containing that module.  You might also make sure that:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=`lldb -P` python
>>> import lldb
```

works correctly.  It should not give the "No module named lldb" error.  If it does then somehow your lldb isn't installed properly.

Comment: You may also need to have lldb in your PATH, it's possible nuclide is using "lldb -P" to find the module, which won't work if it can't find lldb.